Evaluating the integral $\int \cos(2x^3 + \pi/2)dx$
My lecturer proposed to us this question on integration that goes as follows,
$$\int_{}^{}\cos\left( 2x^3+\frac{\pi}{2} \right)dx.$$
How would one go about solving this, sorry if this is a bad question but this is my first. I would like to understand more on why one cannot approach this with a traditional method.

What makes you say that you can't approach this with a traditional method? Was it your lecturer who said this? What was the context that led to them giving you this integral?

Perhaps your lecturer was pulling your leg. Or perhaps you misread the problem. Also: I'm editing your title to better indicate what's in the question.

My lecturer proposed this to my class when we started integration , after writing it on the board he says "there is no answer, i cant even work it". Therefore i was under the impression that it is unworkable unless using a computer to do so.

Did he say anything else about it? Was there any connection to the rest of the material in that class?

You can rewrite $\cos(y+\frac\pi2)$ and expand $\sin(y)$ as a series or try using a special function.

You have just started integration, and your professor gave you this!????!! Yes it's unsolvable in terms of elementary functions

Wolfram Alpha gives a solution using the obscure incomplete gamma function.

I have only just started integration so he may have meant that with the information we have available to us at this time it is impossible.

Unless you're supposed to use some kind of series expansion, it can't be done.

I would double check that the $3$ exponent is supposed to be inside the parenthesis. $\cos^3(2x + \pi/2)$ seems much more reasonable, although still difficult for beginners

The exponent is in the right place I assure you, though this is why i believe he proposed it as unsolvable (for us at least).

Perhaps, since you are just starting out, your professor was trying to explain the difference between differentiation where most equations that are differentiable have a fairly straightforward answer, whereas with integration, even though there is clearly an answer (the area under the curve), you very often can't come up with a straightforward answer, even if you are an expert.
